# RaspiStill - Quality/Size Miss Match - File too big

Tags: python, camera, jpeg, raspberry-pi

Using RaspiStill through a python process shell to take a picture with JPG encoding. I am getting a file that is over two megs. When I reduce the quality down to 50% the file size of the picture taken only drops the by about 200K, or less then a ten percent decrease. When I take that original 2 meg+ file and save it through Paint.Net with the quality set at 85 percent it drops the file size down to 300k, or almost a 90% decrease.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something wrong with the encoder in RaspiStill?

Below is command line that I use to take the picture:
pi@raspberrypi ~/Development/tests $ **raspistill -n -t 100 -q 50 -e jpg -o fullsizejpgsethalfquality.jpg**

Resulting File Size: 2052kb
Resaving the same file though Paint.Net at 85% quality: 319kb

Thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one took a lot of experimentation and an argument over at the Raspberry Pi Forum to solve.

Here is the link to the entire discussion: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=73174&p=527300#p527300

The stats on my final solution are as follows: I dropped the resolution down to 640x480, this produced a file size of 170k. I then dropped the quality down to 10, this is the equivalent to a quality value of 85 for most applications, and it dropped the file size down to 40k. Finally I turned off the thumbnail, which is stored as a bitmap, and it resulted in a final file size of 20k... which is what you would expect from a jpeg that size and quality settings. Here is the final command I used:

pi@raspberrypi ~/Development/tests $ **raspistill -w 640 -h 480 -n -t 100 -q 10 -e  jpg -th none -o vgasize10nothumb.jpg**

The main problem stemmed from how Raspistill interprets the quality value. It uses it as an logarithmic-esk value where there is almost no change from 100 all the way down to 10. The the quality drops off a cliff going down from 10-1. A rather insane development decision IMHO.

As I stated a value of 10 is about the same quality as 85 for most graphics apps, which gives a good apparent quality with a very small file. And is the point of using Jpeg in the first place.

Comment: I was having the exact same issue. Your solution explained what was going on and fixed it. I think it should be marked as the accepted answer (even though it's your own).

Answer (score 1):

I also had some issues with the `-q` (--quality) parameter and didn't undertand it very well, however, why don't you try with `--width` and `--height`? That should give you a solution, look:

```
 raspistill --width 1280 --height 960 --quality 100 -o fullsizejpgsethalfquality3.jpg
```

I added `--quality` but you can ignore it I guess. If I list the contents of the diretory you see 3 different pics. The first two have lkept the full resolution and playing with the -q parameter:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1691812 mar 27 16:57 fullsizejpgsethalfquality.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1492051 mar 27 16:57 fullsizejpgsethalfquality2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  351976 mar 27 17:00 fullsizejpgsethalfquality3.jpg
```

Look at the size, it's a 5 times lighter photo.

Comment: The file is smaller, because the picture is smaller. The default image size for the camera module is 2592x1944. Your image size is half the resolution, which gives a quarter of the pixel count -- and is why you are seeing a photo roughly 25% the size of the defaults. This is still a very big file for a Jpeg. The compression isn't anywhere near what it should be.

Comment: I also had problems with the -q parameters, but if the size is critical then modifying the resolution is the only things you have.

Comment: The default has this size: 1691812 bytes, the one with my command has 351976 bytes (smaller res).  That's a 79% less talking in terms of size. If size is the problem there you are since -q parameter won't work as expected, at least in my case.

Comment: 350k a still very big file?

Comment: For a Jpeg a 350k file is enormously big. And as I stated, when you drop the resolution you are actually making a smaller picture, so of course the file size will be smaller. The magic of Jpegs is that you can have a huge drop in file size with no drop in picture size and very little loss of quality. Try taking your picture again, but this time use a quality setting of 10. You will see what I mean.

Comment: of course, what jpeg is compression by quality loss (not like bmp or so) but as I told if size is something critical, the I gave you a temporal solution. About the -q parameter, I also had those problem,s and to me, it seems not to work properly.